# What is wrong of this code? (Multiple Datasource Oracle)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Currently I have to connect two Oracle Datasources in my Spring Boot proyect. I think that I did well the configuration because Spring validated my connection but when I call a service this always response me "Empty". I think is because the TransactionManager don't change.

This is my project structure:

```
- project
⊢---- config
⊢---- controllers
∟---- models
    ⊢---- dao
    |   ⊢---- db1
    |   ∟---- db2
    ⊢---- entity
    |   ⊢---- db1
    |   ∟---- db2
    ⊢---- services
        ⊢---- db1
        ∟---- db2
```

This are my **entities** classes:

```java
package project.models.entity.db1;

//// IMPORTS

@Entity(name = "User")
@Table(name = "T_USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    ////// CONSTRUCT

    ////// GETTERS & SETTERS

        ////// HASCODE, EQUALS AND TOSTRING

}
```

```java
package project.models.entity.db2;

//// IMPORTS

@Entity(name = "Shareholder")
@Table(name = "Shareholder")
public class Shareholder implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private Integer numberTitles;

    ////// CONSTRUCT

    ////// GETTERS & SETTERS

    ////// HASCODE, EQUALS AND TOSTRING
}
```

This are my **repositories** classes:

```java
package project.models.dao.db1;

//// IMPORTS

@PersistenceContext(name = "db1")
@Repository
public interface IUserDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

```java
package project.models.dao.db2;

//// IMPORTS

@PersistenceContext(name = "db2")
@Repository
public interface IShareholderDao extends JpaRepository<Shareholder, Integer> {

}
```

This are my **services** classes:

```java
package project.models.services.db1.impl;

//// IMPORTS

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {

    @Autowired
    private IUserDao userDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    public List<User> findAll() {
        return userDao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional("transactionManager")
    public User findById(Long id) {
        return userDao.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
```

```java
package project.models.services.db2.impl;

//// IMPORTS

@Service
public class ShareholderServiceImpl implements IShareholderService {

    @Autowired
    private IShareholderDao shareholderDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional("db2TransactionManager")
    public List<Shareholder> findAll() {
        return shareholderDao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional("db2TransactionManager")
    public Shareholder findById(Integer id) {
        return shareholderDao.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
}
```

And this are my **config** classes:

```java
package project.config;

//// IMPORTS

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oracle1")
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager", basePackages = {
        "project.models.dao.db1" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Validated
public class Db1Config {

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String url;

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "project.models.entity.db1" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        em.setPersistenceUnitName("db1");
        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setURL(url);
        dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

```java
package project.config;

//// IMPORTS

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "oracle2")
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "db2TransactionManager", basePackages = {
        "project.models.dao.db2" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Validated
public class Db2Config {

    @NotNull
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @NotNull
    private String url;

    @Bean(name = "db2EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db2EntityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(db2DataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "project.models.entity.db2" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        em.setPersistenceUnitName("db2");
        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "db2DataSource")
    DataSource db2DataSource() throws SQLException {

        OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        dataSource.setURL(url);
        dataSource.setImplicitCachingEnabled(true);
        dataSource.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean(name = "db2TransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager db2TransactionManager() throws SQLException {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(db2EntityManagerFactory().getObject());
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

And my **main** application:

```java
package project;

//// IMPORTS

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableCaching
public class ProjectApplication {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private IShareholderService shareholderService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProjectApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        List<User> user = userService.findAll();
        List<Shareholder> shareholder = shareholderService.findAll();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(user);
        System.out.println(shareholder);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

And always response me:

```
[User [id=39, name=Jack, surname=Sparrow, ...], [...], ...]
[]
```

What is the error? Because I don't see it.

Thank you very much

Comment: The second `shareholderService.findAll()` appears wrong to me. Maybe it is a glitch caused by editing of the code example.

Comment: It should be `List<Usuario> user = userService.findAll();`

Comment: Please check the code you posted. I see class Db1Config twice.

Comment: @bytingbee sorry I updated the post. It was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

In Db2Config class, package being scanned is different than Db1Config.

Db1Config:

```
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "project.models.entity.db1" });
```

Db2Config

```
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "project.models.dao.db2" });
```